# Apex: if condition for if email has bounced or unconfirmed address

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service

Is there something against a `Lead` I can query to see if email sent from Salesforce has bounced or if the email address needs confirming? Can't find anything in the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lead has two fields `EmailBouncedDate` and `EmailBouncedReason`. You can leverage these two fields to identify email is bounce or not. If bounce what was the reason.

Link to doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you have activated the Bounce Management feature to track email delivery to your Contacts, Leads, or Person Accounts, you can use the Bounced Contacts and Bounced Leads standard reports to view a list of email addresses that have bounced email.

Link : [Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005676&typ)

The fields which would be helpful are isEmailBounced, EmailBouncedReason, EmailBouncedDate